# Filtering and copying with preserving folder structure

Tags: windows, filter, copy, backup, directory-structure

We need to manage backup for a set of folders in a Windows Server 2019 without knowing where new files locates. Backup destination does not work with well-known backup applications so we need to copy manually to it.
We are finding a script or tools to filter and copy only files in a certain date range and paste them to destination while preserving folder structure. Folders without update should be empty or at least does not appear in destination.

If anyone has experience about that, please share your idea.

Thanks in advance.
Mountaineer07

No solution yet.
Free and easy-to-find tools did not work.